# How can I get the maximum network card capacity

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter, network-interface, performance-monitor

I want to be able to know what is the maximum capacity of my network card in my Ubuntu 18 machine. I use `sudo nethogs` and gets output like:

```
NetHogs version 0.8.5-2

    PID USER     PROGRAM                    DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
   1724 x        /usr/lib/firefox/firefox   wlp2s0      0.030       0.031 KB/sec
      ? root     unknown TCP                            0.000       0.000 KB/sec

  TOTAL                                                 0.030       0.031 KB/sec
```

It tells me about the bandwidth used in sent/received. But how can I know the capacity (to what extent can I increase the amount of traffic before bottleneck).

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean by "maximum capacity".... Are you trying to figure out the maximum speed of your network adapter?

Comment: @acejavelin yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these commands from the CLI.

Hit **Ctrl + Alt + T** from the desktop, or load up your preferred terminal.

Find your adapter name using **ifconfig**.
Use:
**dmesg | grep eth0**

Or:
**mii-tool -v  eth0**